# Appixia on Prestashop 1.4.9 - How do I add allow 2 CategoryId under same filter? Is this possible?

Tags: prestashop, appixia

Appixia on Prestashop 1.4.9

I'm using the BasicCategoryListActivity to show categories in my store.
I'm trying to filter the category list according to a specific id.
How do I add 2 CategoryId under same filter? Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

This answer is updated for Appixia Mobile Engine 5 with Prestashop module 1.0.4

The modules you are currently using are mostly intended to work on a single category id filter. Much like anything with Appixia, you can usually work around most limitations and do whatever you want. Here are two ideas:

**Workaround 1: Implement this using a plugin override**

With this approach you don't need to change anything in your app.. you can stay with your existing module and use a *single* category id filter. Put a filter for a *single* category id and make up some large nonexistent number for it (like 1001).

What we will do actually is make the server reply with products for both categories at the same time when category 1001 is requested.

You can see some examples of plugin overrides [here](http://kb.appixia.com/cart%3aplugin-overrides-prestashop).

The override we need is in `Items.php`. Look at the function `overrideItemListFilters`, it's going to be perfect for your needs. Just find a filter type of `Equal` with value `1001` and change it in the override to an `InGroup` filter with your 2 category ids.

**Workaround 2: Switch to a more advanced item list module in app**

A different alternative approach is only by changing your app and without touching the server. The basic item list activities are fairly limited. If you move to a more powerful item list module in your app, you will have more control over your filters. Take a look at this [tutorial](http://kb.appixia.com/frontend%3atutorials%3acustomitemlist1). Item lists like `ItemGridView` support any filter you want, so you can specify `InGroup` directly.